# Flutter build web in release mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, release

Is is possible to build flutter web in release mode? The only commmand I found to run on web was either :

flutter run -d chrome

but it's in debug

or I use :
flutter run -d web-server --web-port 5000 --web-hostname localhost

to run a local webserver to avoid having to use a new chrome everytime I debug anything.

My problem is the following and pretty simple :  I have code that crashes in release mode when webApp is built and deployed on github pages, but the stack is impossible to understand, also this very code doesn't crash when I test it in debug mode ( again the error stack looks like this ):

```
main.dart.js:4315 Uncaught TypeError: n.gawc is not a function
    at main.dart.js:22638:13
    at aAA.a (main.dart.js:5512:62)
    at aAA.$2 (main.dart.js:39196:14)
    at Object.E (main.dart.js:5498:10)
    at Object.QE (main.dart.js:22648:10)
```

the javascript is obfuscated so I don't know at which point it's hapenning, and if I want to test anything I need to build for web and upload on github pages, then wait 1 hour for it to be live to be able to see my prints in the console which are placed completely blind.

Is it possible to build for web in release mode locally?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asks about building for web in release mode. So the following does that for you.

`flutter build web --release`

To actually run a local release version. You just need.

`flutter run --release`

See this for more info https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes

Comment: oh yeah since my phone was always plugged in I thought it was impossible to launch in release mode only on web, but when you plug it out the console will ask if you want to launch chrome :), also I guess "flutter build web" is already in release mode

Comment: If you are using VSCode as an editor you can switch the output device you are using without having to un-plug. At the bottom right part of the window you should see your device name if it's plugged in. Press that and it will open a drop down to select another device to run on.

Answer (score 0):

look out for expanded widget if you have used it. It might be the culprit.